# Server not responding

Tags: java

I'm making a server/client application in Java but it doesn't really work the way I want it to.

I make a connection and everything goes fine but then it does nothing. I'm thinking it doesn't come to my thread for accepting the client.

Here's my code.

Networking Thread:

```
package libgdx.server;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.net.*;


public class NetworkingThread extends Thread {
private Socket sock= null;
 private int ID;

public NetworkingThread(Socket sock){
    super("Multiple connection thread!");

    this.sock = sock;

 }

@Override
public void run()  {
   try{
   System.out.println("In the Method run() in the thread!");

       PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(),true);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine,outputLine;
    AlphaProtocol alpha = new AlphaProtocol();
    outputLine = alpha.ProcessInput(null);
    out.println(outputLine);

    out.println("Welcome to the Server! Hope you enjoy your stay.");
    while ((inputLine  = in.readLine()) != null){
        outputLine = alpha.ProcessInput(inputLine);
        out.println(outputLine);
        if (outputLine.equals("Bye!")){
            break;
        }
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
   sock.close();
   }catch(IOException ioe){
       ioe.printStackTrace();
       System.err.println("Error in the Tread of Connecting and Method Run()");
   }

}

}
```

This is the tread on the server for accepting clients and handling them :)

Main class on server:

```
package libgdx.server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

/**
 *
 * @author Saturn
 */
 public class MainServer {
 private static ServerSocket Server = null;
 private static boolean networking = true;


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    try{
        System.out.println("Server listening!");
        Server = new ServerSocket(4444);


    }catch (IOException io){
     System.err.println("Error while making ServerSocket!");
     System.exit(-1);
    }
    while (networking)
    System.out.println("Networking!");

        new NetworkingThread(Server.accept()).start();     

}
```

}

Protocol of server:

```
  /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
  * and open the template in the editor.
*/
package libgdx.server;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

/**
*
* @author Saturn
*/
public class AlphaProtocol {
    private static final int CONNECTING = -1;

    private static final int MOVE = 0;
    private static final int NEW_PLAYER = 1;
    private int state  =  CONNECTING;
    private Calendar Date;
    private Date Time = Date.getTime();

public String ProcessInput(String input){
    String output = null;
    String name = null;
    String X= null,Y = null;

    if (input.equals("connect")){
      System.out.println("Connection granted!");

        output =  Time + ":" + "Got a Connection over here!";
    }
    if (input.equals("Bye!")){
        System.err.println("Client said Bye!");
    }
    return output;

}
```

}

Now these are the client files:

Desktop:

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package libgdx.test;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogl.JoglApplication;

 /**
  *
  * @author Saturn
  */
public class Desktop {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    new JoglApplication(new LibGDXTest(),"Test #1",640,480,false);

}
```

}

LibGDXTest:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
   package libgdx.test;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.jogl.JoglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import java.util.Scanner;

 /**
 *
 * @author Saturn
 */
  public class LibGDXTest implements ApplicationListener {
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture texture;
    BitmapFont font;
    Vector2 textPosition = new Vector2(100, 100);
    Vector2 textDirection = new Vector2(1, 1);
    String ip;
    int port;
    Networking net = new Networking();

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */


      @Override
    public void create() {
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello, welcome to LibGDX Network test: #1 ");
    System.out.println("Type the server ip in:");
   ip = in.next();
   System.out.println("Type the server port in:");
   port = in.nextInt();
   System.out.println("IP:" + ip + "Port:" + port);
   net.Connect(ip,port);

   }

    @Override
    public void resize(int i, int i1) {

  }

   @Override
   public void render() {

  }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

   }

   @Override
   public void resume() {

   }

   @Override
  public void dispose() {

   }
```

}

Networking: is the class that handeles all the networking on the client side :)

```
   /*
   * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
   * and open the template in the editor.
   */
  package libgdx.test;

   /**
    *
   * @author Saturn
   */
      import java.io.BufferedReader;
      import java.io.IOException;
       import java.io.InputStreamReader;
       import java.io.PrintWriter;
       import java.net.*;
     import java.util.logging.Level;
     import java.util.logging.Logger;

   public class Networking {

   private Socket Client;
    private  PrintWriter out;
   private BufferedReader in;


   public void Connect(String arg1, int arg2){
       try{
           Client = new Socket(arg1,arg2);
                out = new PrintWriter(Client.getOutputStream(),true);
             in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Client.getInputStream()));

        }catch(UnknownHostException uhk) {
           System.err.println("Cannot find host:" + arg1);
           System.exit(-1);

      }catch (IOException ioe) {
           System.err.println("Cannot get I/O for the connection:" + arg1);
          System.exit(-1);

       }

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String fromUser;
        String fromServer;
        try {
            while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
                if (fromServer.equals("Bye!"))
                  break;

              fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
          if (fromUser != null) {
                  System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                  out.println(fromUser);
           }
          }
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Networking.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }



   }
  }
```

When I run the application,

I get this:

```
   Client:    Hello, welcome to LibGDX Network test: #1 
   Type the server ip in:
   127.0.0.1 // My INPUT!
   Type the server port in:
   4444  // My INPUT!
   IP:127.0.0.1Port:4444
```

And the server:

```
Server listening!
Networking!
Networking!
Networking!
Networking!
Networking!
Networking!
Networking!
```

It just prints "Networking!".

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do note that in your NetworkingThread class of `package libgdx.server;` you are calling `outputLine = alpha.ProcessInput(null);` of Class AlphaProtocol, but since you are providing null as an argument, so that function returns null as defined in your method. Since Variable **input** is null for which no condition satisfies to true, hence the output always remains null, which is returned from this method.

```
public String ProcessInput(String input){
  String output = null;
  String name = null;
  String X= null,Y = null;

  if (input.equals("connect")){
    System.out.println("Connection granted!");

      output =  Time + ":" + "Got a Connection over here!";
  }
  if (input.equals("Bye!")){
      System.err.println("Client said Bye!");
  }
  return output;
}
```

so in the Networking Class of Client side on receiving that null value, in this code of yours `while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) , the Client shuts itself down.
So please try to provide some String value in place of null here,`outputLine = alpha.ProcessInput("Hello Client");`

I guess that's the issue you should be aiming at to make things work.

Regards`

Comment: Thanks! would post you up if I would :)

Comment: Sorry typo. its if i could I would give you +rep :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in your program, which would be obvious if you used the debugger. you have written

```
while (networking)
    System.out.println("Networking!");
```

As `networking` is always true, this runs endlessly.  I suggest using the IDEs formatting and place `{` and `}` for your loops until you are confident you don't need them.

Comment: In the java server socket tutorial they do it like that, so i thought it was nessecary thanks for clearing that up!Thanks! would post you up if I would :)

Comment: Sorry typo. its if i could I would give you +rep